# Email sytem ERD

Tags: mysql, database, email, many-to-many, erd

Please Pardon my bad english, 
Scenario: a user can send a report task to group(a,b,c) of email ids (sendlist), so sendlist contains of many email ids(cc1 , cc2,cc3) , and one list can be used by many users for their report task. the problem is i have completely gone blank how to do this in ERD. i have made three table one report task , a table of email ids i named it CC. and send list table .

now my query is i want to select all CC's ID that are in sendlist 'A' where reporttask.sendlist_id = sendlist.id

report task table contains fields as

```
id,user_id,content,sendlist_id. sendlist contain, id, report_id and cc_id.and cc table contains id,name,email_id.
```

So what i want is group of cc's in a sendlist where task report sendlist ids and sendlist id are same, and one more thing my structure does not shows group of cc's hold by one sendlist , do i need to change field in these table ??

Comment: Provide more description like how is your table structure and some code what have you tried.

Comment: thanku so much for the reply Farhad

Comment: report task table contains fields as id,user_id,content,sendlist_id. sendlist contain, id, report_id and cc_id.and cc table contains id,name,email_id. So what i want is group of cc's in a sendlist where task report sendlist ids and sendlist id are same, and one more thing my structure does not shows group of cc's hold by one sendlist , do i need to change field in these table ???